# throwaway classloaders with byte-buddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

In our application we are using certain classloaders for particular jobs (Eclipse environment). Byte Buddy is maintaining these classloaders and stores a reference on them in the class Nexus. We are closing and deleting these classloaders. But the references on these classloaders are still hold within the Nexus class.
Is there a possibility to say ByteBuddy that a classloaders goes absolute and therefore can be deleted from the classloader collection maintained by ByteBuddy?

Comment: You can track this issue here: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/210

Comment: This issue is now resolved on master. Class loaders are only referenced weakly from now on. In order to clean the meta data, you do however still need to register a custom `InitializationStrategy` where you can pass a `NexusAccessor` which in turn takes a reference queue as an argument. This way you can clean up any meta data whilst class loaders are dereferenced automatically.

Comment: Nitpick: you mean obsolete not absolute.

Comment: This is now released starting from Byte Buddy 1.5.5.

Answer (score 1):

The `Nexus` class serves as an intermediate dispatcher for classes that have an active initialization strategy. Classes are written into this nexus either because:

1. You are using an `AgentBuilder` with an `InitilaizationStrategy.SelfInjecting` in addition to using an active `LoadedTypeInitializer` for this type.
2. You are using `TypeResolutionStrategy.Active` when defining a new type.

In both cases, the `Nexus` receives an entry right before a class is loaded where the entry should be removed right after. The concept is as follows: Upon (1) or (2), before loading a class, Byte Buddy registers a loaded type initializer within the nexus:

```
LoadedTypeInitializer initializer = instrument("Foo");
Nexus.register("Foo", classLoaderOfFoo, 42);
```

In order to assure that the class is fully initialized (e.g. static fields are set), before any code is executed, Byte Buddy then adds the following code to the beginning of the type initializer:

```
class Foo {
  static {
    Nexus.initialize(Foo.class, 42);
  }
}
```

This way, Byte Buddy can assure that `Foo` is fully initialized before its first use.

Most likely, you do not run every instrumented class's initializer before disposing a class loader such that the references get stuck. I will think of a way to resolve this problem.

**UPDATE**: This is now possible and will be released as a part of Byte Buddy 1.5.5. Class loaders are now only referenced weakly by a `Nexus` and it is possible to register a custom `InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Split` (the default) which takes a `NexusAccessor` as a single argument. Such a nexus accessor allows the registration of a reference queue to clean up such references. For example:

```
ReferenceQueue<ClassLoader> refQueue = new ReferenceQueue<ClassLoader>();
NexusAccessor accessor = new NexusAccessor(refQueue);

new AgentBuilder.Default()
  .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Split(accessor));
```

Now, any reference that is registered within the nexus will be enqueued to `refQueue` once a class loader is garbage collected. You can remove such references from the nexus via `NexusAccessor.clean(ref)`.